# convert iis web config to apache htaccess for laravel

Tags: php, apache, iis, laravel-5, web

i need to convert this to .haccess. I need to use it with Laravel because I have a problem with my current web server config that I can't read any css or folders from /var/www/globapp/public like adminlte. and yes i check  the permissions and try with -R 777 for this dir and storge dir. and it's return with 404. now i'm using apache. but i think i miss somethings.
Thanks.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
~                                                                                                                                                                                                    
~
```

Answer (score -1):

It was not an problem with webserver. the problem is Laravel try to open public instead of public. like this

/var/www/globapp/public/public/adminlte

I can't fix the code but i'm a server man. so i slove this with soft link.

```
ln -s /var/www/globapp/public/ /var/www/globapp/public/public
```

and vola !